# HTML5 img tag dimensions

Tags: html

What is the more "correct" way to define `<img>`'s width and height?
Will it be directory through the tag with its "width" and "height" attributes, or would it be better to do it via CSS `img { width:...; height... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is definitely the right way, there really is no wrong way, to specify the width and height on the image tag itself. Especially during the rendering phase of your site, having the dimensions specified there, will be a small performance improvement as the browser does not need to try and calculate the size of the images.

[From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-map-element.html#attr-dim-width):

"Author requirements: The width and height attributes on img, iframe, embed, object, video, and, when their type attribute is in the Image Button state, input elements may be specified to give the dimensions of the visual content of the element".

Comment: Calculating the image size probably takes less time than parsing these two attributes.

Comment: From the spec it is clear that these attributes are not required and in modern browsers leaving this off is most likely not going to be an issue but, for older browsers, specifying the width and height on the element is definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

For a single unique content image used once it there's no reason not to use inline `width`/`height` attributes. They're still valid, even in Strict.

Circumstances a CSS rule would be better:

- there are a number of instances of the image, or multiple images all the same size. A rule would allow you to cut down the amount of markup you have to write;
- the image is part of a layout feature rather than content; a different stylesheet might want to resize it;
- I might want to use more complex sizing rules than `width`/`height` attributes allow, such as `%`-sizing or `max-width`.

Answer (score 0):

All styling of elements should be done using CSS. The height and width attributes are considered to be no longer valid in most cases. This way you separate style and layout from function. It should also lead to cleaner html code and smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are "correct".

The usage depends on personal preferences or political (enterprise) decisions.

I myself think it is better to place it in the css.

Answer (score 0):

You should always prefer CSS to HTML-attributes. HTML is meant to define the structure, while CSS tells the browser how to render it.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are [fine](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/the-canvas-element.html#attr-dim-width). The `width` and `height` attributes are optional. If none are specified, the resource's dimensions will be used.

I would prefer to specify them in proper `width` and `height` attributes because they are closely related to the `src` used. It doesn't make sense to keep them in a style sheet.

From the spec (emphasis mine):

> The width and height attributes on img, iframe, .... and input elements **may** be specified to give the dimensions of the visual content of the element (the width and height respectively, relative to the nominal direction of the output medium), in CSS pixels. The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers.